# Cannot set Configuration from JSON appsettings file in .NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Since there's no ConfigurationManager class in .NET Core, now I have to set config in appsettings.json instead web.config

According to [this](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/new-configuration-model-asp-net-core/) blog post I have to set my configuration there, so I did like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },

  "Conexion": {
    "name" : "empresas",
    "connectionString": "Data Source=empresas;Initial Catalog=CATALMA; Integrated Security=True;",
    "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
  }
}
```

I just writed that "Conexion".

Now I created in a ViewModels folder the following class:

```
public class ConexionConfig 
    {
       public string name { get; set; }
        public string connectionString { get; set; }
        public string providerName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, In Startup.cs, in the ConfigureServices method, I have to add it by:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.Configure<ConexionConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Conexion"));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

But unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 
     'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to
     'System.Action<ConexionConfig>'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to this? I've got exactly the same issue.

Comment: Yes I did, but I change appsettings.json content to match an example that I see somewhere else.

Comment: See posted answer

Answer (score 71):

**Firstly**, you need to add the following nuget package to your ASP Core Project.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
```

The extension methods contained in the package will allow you to configure the strongly typed configuration the way you originally wanted to do it.

```
services.Configure<ConexionConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Conexion"));
```

**Alternatively**, you could use the binder directly like another answer in this thread suggests without important the previous package but rather:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
```

This means that you would have to explicitly enable the options on the pipeline, and bind the action. That is:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<ConexionConfig>(x => Configuration.GetSection("Conexion").Bind(x));
```

Comment: This answer is helpful. Just a note, with **ASP.NET Core 2.0**, that additional NuGet is not required.

Comment: @ArghyaC - something must have changed in the library dependencies because I've found **you do need** the NuGet package. **ASP.Net Core 2.1**

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer because this worked for me.  I'm using .NET Core 2.2.  Used the first answer not the alternative.

Comment: Got to this issue after upgrade of .NET Core from 2.2 to 3.1. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I installed Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions -Version 3.1.2 and works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

Try installing the nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` and use it´s `Bind` method:

```
 services.Configure<ConexionConfig>(x => Configuration.GetSection("Conexion").Bind(x));
```

You also have to install the options package `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` and add support for it if you want to inject your options class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    //..
}
```

Now you can inject `IOptions<ConexionConfig>` in your controllers and views.

Comment: This would work you are right, but if one wanted to configure it in the same way many tutorials illustrate the problem then one only needs to add the correct package. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I based on a example somewhere else. Changed appsettings.json to something like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=myserver\\sql08;Initial Catalog=enterprises;User id=userAPP;Password=mypassword;"
    }
  }
}
```

ConexionConfig class changed to this:

```
 public class ConexionConfig
        {

        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then In Startup.cs

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.Configure<ConexionConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Data:DefaultConnection"));
        }
...
```

Is important to include `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` in this file.

Comment: I think the only difference between your original question and this answer is that you added the correct package along the way. See my answer...