# ServiceCollection IOptions<> won't bind properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicecollection

I am trying to bind some configurable settings. The values are provided via the app-settings.local.json. The Model to bind to is called Configurable Settings. I have attempted to follow a few tutorials and troubleshoot the issue:

1. https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/
2. https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/411
3. [Cannot set Configuration from JSON appsettings file in .NET Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515965/cannot-set-configuration-from-json-appsettings-file-in-net-core-project/38520496)
4. [ServiceCollection returns null for IOptions even though GetSection is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019988/servicecollection-returns-null-for-ioptions-even-though-getsection-is-working)

I have attempted to follow the advice given here and apply it in my own application. I could not get it to work after 4 hours of trying. Either I lack the basic knowledge needed to implement this or I'm overlooking something.

My ConfigurableSettings class is structured as follows:

```
    public class ConfigurableSettings
    {
        public AppSettings _AppSettings;
        public DgeSettings _DgeSettings;
        
        public class AppSettings
        {
            [JsonProperty("SoftDelete")] 
            public bool SoftDelete { get; set; }
        }

        public class DgeSettings
        {
            [JsonProperty("zipFileUrl")] 
            public string zipFileUrl { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("sourceFileUrl")] 
            public string sourceFileUrl { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

My ConfigureServices is structured as follows:

```
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string[] args)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection(); 
            
            serviceCollection.AddOptions();
            
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .AddJsonFile("app-settings.local.json", true)
                                .AddJsonFile("app-settings.json", false)
                                .Build();

            serviceCollection.Configure<ConfigurableSettings>(options => configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(options));
            serviceCollection.Configure<ConfigurableSettings>(options => configuration.GetSection("DgeSettings").Bind(options));

            var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            var options = services.GetService<IOptions<ConfigurableSettings>>();

            serviceCollection.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
                loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            });

            serviceCollection.AddServices(configuration);
            serviceCollection.AddNopCommerceServices(configuration);

            serviceCollection.AddTransient<Comparator>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<UpdateManager>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<DgeRequestAuthenticator>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISourceConnector, DgeConnector>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IDestinationConnector, NopCommerceConnector>();
        }
```

My app-settings.local.json is configured as follows:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "SoftDelete": true
  },

  "DgeSettings": {
    "zipFileUrl" : "www.example-url.com",
    "sourceFileUrl" : "www.example-url.com"
  }
}
```

When I attempt to use it in a class, I call it in my constructor as follows:

```
private readonly ConfigurableSettings _settings;
        
        public AlphaBetaService(IOptions<ConfigurableSettings> settings)
        {
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }
```

Could someone help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546723/how-to-read-values-from-multiple-json-files-in-net-core/65547297#65547297

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read values from multiple json files in .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546723/how-to-read-values-from-multiple-json-files-in-net-core)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It certainly helped me to get closer. I can see that it recognizes the data in my debugger, but it won't bind it to the model. Is it perhaps because I am using a difficult model? I Configure my AppSettings on ConfigurableSettings.AppSettings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you use `ConfigureServices` method in your project, actually the `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type `IServiceCollection`.

Change your ConfigureServices like below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("app-settings.local.json", true)
                            .Build();
        services.Configure<ConfigurableSettings>(configuration);

        //...
    }
}
```

Also change your model design like below:

```
public class ConfigurableSettings
{
    public AppSettings AppSettings{ get; set; }
    public DgeSettings DgeSettings { get; set; }        
}
public class AppSettings
{
    [JsonProperty("SoftDelete")]
    public bool SoftDelete { get; set; }
}

public class DgeSettings
{
    [JsonProperty("zipFileUrl")]
    public string zipFileUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sourceFileUrl")]
    public string sourceFileUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem because you cannot declare your model the way you've done. It will warn that a member with the same name is already declared. I fixed the issue by dumbing down my model. Now it's just ConfigurableSettings with two regions rather than two classes.

Comment: Please read carefully. The AppSettings and DgeSettings is outside the `ConfigurableSettings` not in it. Otherwise it will warn the same name is already declared.